# How to hide a part of a string or label text in C# window form

Tags: c#

```
Public Void Show()
{
label1.Text="My Text";
string varTest=Label1.Text;
MessageBox.Show(varText);
}
```

i want to hide "My" of Label1 Text but when assign to varTest i want to show complete Text Mean "My Text"

Comment: A Label shows all text that you assign to it. That is simply how a Label works.

Comment: Alex K i want to show part of label text when form load not to show complete label text

Comment: Peter B  i know how to use label but i have situation in which label text is shown according to rule mean that when user have rights to show a complete label text or not

Comment: @kamranafridi, to show text dependent on user rights you can use `if` statement to choose needed text, you can't show some part of text.

Comment: Thank you all i solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the question isn't *really* answered yet, because nobody presented a solution, in which a part of the label is hidden. However, this is (of course) possible. You simply have to derive the WinForms label and change the way it is painted:

```
public class SpecialLabel : Label
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        if (!Text.StartsWith("My "))
            return;
        var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericDefault);
        stringFormat.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new []{new CharacterRange(0, 3)});
        var bounds = Rectangle.Round(e.Graphics.MeasureCharacterRanges("My ",
                Font, e.ClipRectangle, stringFormat)[0]
            .GetBounds(e.Graphics));
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(BackColor), bounds);
    }
}
```

Now use `SpecialLabel` instead of your label, and everytime the text in the label starts with "My " this part won't be printed. You can, of course, still modify this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you So much MetaColon i am learning dotnet from scratch that is why thing are difficult to me. your code work perfectly thank you so much again

Comment: Hi @kamranafridi if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.